# C# Email Regex - Blacklist characters such as "

Tags: c#, regex, email-validation

I have the the following regex that works well to validate an email:

```
[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\.)+[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])
```

But I want to add to the regex to make it fail if any part of the email contains certain characters such as `"`.

Comment: FWIW [don't validate email addresses !](http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/)

Answer (score 0):

if you add

```
(?<!".*)
```

to the front of the current regex expression, the regex match will fail if the email address contains a "

Comment: Or just `(?!.*")` at the beginning of the expression :)

Comment: how does your regex differ in functionality to the one provided?

Comment: You're doing a non-fixed length negative lookbehind which is very expensive but what matters the most not all regex flavor supports it. So to make your regex more portable, you may use a negative lookahead.